# Mongoose find() and append to array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I am trying to asynchronously retrieve some data from a database and then append those values in an array I need for some other things, I have this function:

```
function retrieveProduct(SKU, callback) {
Products.find({
  SKU: key
}, function (err, doc) {

  if (err) {
    callback(err, null);
  } else {
    callback(null, doc[0]);
  }
});
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
for (var key in orders) {

retrieveProduct(key, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  products_found[key] = doc
  console.log(doc);
});

}
console.log(products_found);
}
```

Where `orders` is a list of IDs.

The problem is that when I try to append `doc` to `products_found` nothing is being appended and nothing is logged to the console. Moreover, ESlint is telling me not to make functions within a loop.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you mind using promises instead?, also in the first function, you have passed `SKU` but used `key` instead i guess.

Comment: I've noticed that even if I use `.then()` I am still getting the same problem. I am definitely missing something.